# Resolved: MAMP Php can't exec ('convert') after Homebrew ImageMagick install

Tags: php, osx-lion, imagemagick, mamp, homebrew

I installed Imagemagick using Homebrew on Lion, everything is fine except that it doesn't work at all when being called from php. Console:

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.1-1 2011-07-29 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP   

$ which convert
/usr/local/bin/convert
```

PHP:

```
echo exec ('convert -version');
```

or
    exec('convert -version', $output);
    var_dump($output);

Produces nothing (or an empty array).

```
exec ('/usr/local/bin/convert') // works, but
exec ('which convert') // doesn't
```

I need to test this locally to make sure I can detect convert in production environment. But I can't properly test it. The PATH is set and it works in Terminal, but not from PHP.

**Resolved:**

Turns out, for php to work `convert` should be in `/usr/bin/` so this solved it:

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/convert /usr/bin/convert
```

**Update**

It was becasue of MAMP, here is the fix: http://firedevcom.tumblr.com/post/22791937644/fix-for-homebrew-imagemagick-and-mamp

Open /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars

And comment out the following lines:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Done.

Comment: Is convert in PHP's path? You may have to specify an `/absolute/path/to/convert` in the exec() call. Remember that the environment in a PHP exec() call can be significantly different from what you get at a shell prompt.

Comment: Hmm the thing is - everything works on production server, just not with Homebrew. I thought PATH should be inherited into exec sandbox, no?

Comment: php's shell environment is completely different from a user shell environment. you can't compare them directly. try doing `exec('echo $PATH');` to see what the shell's got going. PHP will inherit the Apache environment.

Comment: Awesome! That worked! You probably saved me a couple of more hours. I am very grateful @aorcsik!

Comment: Just editing envvars didn't work for me. I had to create symbolic links in /usr/bin/ too to get Imagick to work in exec. Also, remember to restart servers in MAMP after you edit envvars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding my own answer here so you can vote:

It was caused by MAMP, here is the fix: http://firedevcom.tumblr.com/post/22791937644/fix-for-homebrew-imagemagick-and-mamp

Open `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars`

And comment out the following lines:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Done.

Comment: Also works for XAMPP, path: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/envvars

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/convert /usr/bin/convert
```

Comment: You saved me! Now I can use exec command without including absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that convert in is the server's PATH environment variable. Or just specify the full path:

```
exec('/usr/local/bin/convert -version');
```

Comment: It is in the PATH in console, but not in php's exec, however on production server everything seem to work fine. And I need to be able to detect imagemagick automatically. It works on Linux, but not with homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

The `exec` returns the last line from the result of the command which happens to be an empty string.
If you want to get the output, just do something like this:

```
exec('convert -version', $output);
var_dump($output); // it is an array which filled with every line of output from the command
```

Comment: Use `exec('convert -version 2>&1', $output);` if you also want errors in `$output`.

Comment: Of course I used var_dump too, it just doesn't return anything

Comment: So what about use the full path of convert?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `exec("PATH=\$PATH:/usr/local/bin; convert file.pdf file.png");` It will add convert to PATH on runtime.

Comment: this is exactly what i need. But here i need to get a trick on my PHP code because i don't need the PATH to my live machine. Do you know a way to set on the mac this export path global?

Answer (score 1):

instead of just exec("convert .... ");
use a full path. you can get it by typing the terminal

> type convert

you should get something like:
convert is hashed (/opt/local/bin/convert)

so now use:

> exec("/opt/local/bin/convert .... ");

[credits to @Nikki]

after that comment out

> DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
>   export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH

in /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/envvars

Comment: You will quickly learn that this is a bad habit once your projects reach production stage.