# Php exec command to convert an image

Tags: php, macos, permissions, exec, mamp

I'm trying to use the imagemagick command "convert" to create a .tif image from a .png one.

What I've come with is:

```
$exec = "/opt/local/bin/convert -adaptive-resize 150% ".$pos.".png ".$pos.".tif";
exec($exec);
```

If I run into CLI "which convert" I get that path: `/opt/local/bin/convert` . I've also tried without the path, only `/opt/local/bin/convert -adaptive-resize 150% ".$pos.".png ".$pos.".tif` and `/etc/local/bin/convert -adaptive-resize 150% ".$pos.".png ".$pos.".tif`.

If I'm running that command into the terminal it works as expected but when I'm trying to use it from the PHP script it doesn't work.

EDIT:
I've also tried without success to create a .sh file with the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 1.png 1.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 2.png 2.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 3.png 3.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 4.png 4.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 5.png 5.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 6.png 6.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 7.png 7.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 8.png 8.tif
convert -adaptive-resize 150% 9.png 9.tif
```

If I run it from terminal it works like a charm.
Instead if I try to execute it from a simple PHP file it doesn't create any .tif file.

```
<?php
$exec = "./convertpngtif.sh";
exec($exec);
?>
```

Comment: do a var_dump($exec) to see what is generated, might be a problem with spaces

Comment: string(56) "/opt/local/bin/convert -adaptive-resize 150% 1.png 1.tif"

Comment: try these: `error_reporting(E_ALL); var_dump($_SERVER); echo getcwd();`, also look at apache's error.log.

Comment: So is 1.png in the same path of the script?

Comment: Does 1.png have read permissions for user www-data? or even has it write permissions in the directory? (for creating the new file) (if you are in linux)

Comment: I'm on a mac platform. How can I check it?

Comment: Open a terminal, `cd` into the directory and do `ls -la`. Look at the permissions of `.` and `1.png`.

Comment: `ls -al DIRECTORY|grep '\s\./'|cut -d ' ' -f 1` will show you permissions of given DIRECTORY.

Comment: permission of . drwxrwxrwx, permission of 1.png -rw-r--r--

Comment: This script used to work with an older version of MAMP. Now I've updated it and doesn't work anymore. Makes me think that there are permissions problems.

Comment: Question edited with new details...

Comment: What if you try `__DIR__`  . '/myscript.sh'?

Comment: @hek2mgl I've tried but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there an error when you execute the command (`echo exec($exec);`)? Your PHP script may not have access to `/opt/local/bin/convert` when running as your HTTP server (as opposed to CLI mode). Such an error would show in the return value of `exec()`.

Comment: Do spaces appear in $post? If true, please use escapeshellcmd(): http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Comment: Are you even in the right folder? Does `<?php print getcwd(); ?>` point to the right directory? Does `<?php is_file('1.tif') ?>` return `1`?

Comment: I'm trying this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163497/resolved-mamp-php-cant-exec-convert-after-homebrew-imagemagick-install

Comment: Finally found the solution.

You can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163497/resolved-mamp-php-cant-exec-convert-after-homebrew-imagemagick-install

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The clue is in Hieu Nguyen answer above: when you run from command line with `PHP -r`, it works. When you run in the browser, it doesn't. This leads to one of three possible issues.

The critical thing to remember is that when you run exec, the script, user, path and working directory will be run with the same user/permissions that PHP is running at.

When running PHP in command line, PHP will be run as the user is who you are logged in as ("you"), and therefore exec() will also run "you". This will also be the same user that you use to write the shell script in. The permissions are therefore the same as yours, and it works (great).

When PHP runs in Apache (or IIS) then is may or may not be "you". In your case, it obviously isn't as the script doesn't work - PHP is probably running as "apache" or "http" or "www" or some similarly named user.

This leads to one of three possible issues. So what to check:

1) and 2) Path AND working directory.

Been suggested above one at a time, but it's safer to stipulate absolute paths (i.e. full paths, starting at root `/`) to all files - the executable command, the input file and the output file. This rules out any differences in paths or working directories that may arise. If you uses shell script, stipulate full paths to the shell script and full paths within it (or set paths / directories at the top)

3) Permissions

Again suggested above, but everyone's been concentrating on the files. But have you checked permissions of the `convert` executable command itself?

Also with the shell script, have you set permissions of that to executable for the user PHP is running as? rwxr--r-- owned by "you" isn't satisfactory if you're running as a different user from within apache.

There are a couple of other solutions if struggling with those:

1. you can make PHP run as "you" even in Apache using fastCGI install. This way you know the user/path/working directory that you are running both PHP scripts as. (I'd still recommend full paths, but still alleviates permission issues)
2. you can debug the script by logging in as "apache" or "www" or "http" etc and setting permissions / paths so your script now works.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [php imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) instead of **exec** function.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a permission issue to me. First you need to debug your php call by using `system()` instead of `exec()` (to get the full output) on terminal:

```
php -r 'system("/opt/local/bin/convert -adaptive-resize 150% 1.png 1.tif");'
```

I bet then you will see the exact error. There are 2 cases in my opinion:

- The destination folder doesn't have write permission, in that case you might want to change that folder's permission to 777.
- The `/opt/local/bin/convert` doesn't have execute permission, in that case you have to check each folder permission from `/opt` to `/opt/local`, etc. and give each of them at least permission 755.

In both cases, use `ls -la` to get permission of each folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I run this command everything works as expected and the tif file is created. It gives me no errors.

Answer (score 2):

I would use PHP imagemagick's interface for this. Something like this:

```
<?php
$image = new Imagick( "image.png" );
$height=$image->getImageHeight()*1.5; // 150% size
$width=$image->getImageWidth()*1.5;  // 150% size
$image->resizeImage( $width, $height,  imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1 );
$image->setImageFormat( "tif" );
$image->writeImage( "image.tif" );
$image->clear(); 
$image->destroy(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

**THIS ANSWER WORKS ON LINUX/MAC**

I know this is an old question - but I had a similar problem.
A way to execute shell commands without having path issues is to
create a new login shell
use

```
/bin/bash -l
```

so bash acts as like it is a login shell and all pathinfo is set.
use -c to add the command as string

```
$exec = "/bin/bash -lc 'convert -adaptive-resize 150% ".$pos.".png".$pos.".tif'";
exec($exec,$out,$rcode);
```

you can use this to get the path to convert by

```
/bin/bash -lc 'which convert'
```

and work without the bash part

It is still required that the permissions to convert are set and that
the user php runs on is allowed to login.
So a login shell in /etc/passwd (ubuntu/debian) must be set

Answer (score 1):

As far as i see, you're trying to use ImageMagick to do convert an image.

PHP has an `Imagick` library which needs to be installed. If you have root access, you can easily do it, and use the imagick library wrapper functions to convert the image (no need to run command line).

[Here is the documentation to php Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)

You can check with `phpinfo();` if imagick is installed.

Comment: `Imagick` is nothing but a wrapper around the executable, OPs problem should persist...

Comment: It's NOT a wrapper around the executable. If you read the source code of Imagick (which you can, as it's open source), you will see that. ( https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/ )

Answer (score 1):

See if you have correct permissions for write.

In linux common username for Apache server is www-data

In the console:

```
cd /var/www (or where you are saving your php files)
ls -la (You will see permissions)
sudo chown www-data:youruser thisfolder (change primary user to www-data and group to youruser)
sudo chmod 775 thisfilder (change permissions, write read exec for user and usergroup and read for others.
```

Comment: So, if my username is Giorgio. I would be typing:
sudo chown www-data:Giorgio thisfolder ? I've tried to type the path instead of "thisfolder". But I get this error chown: Giorgio : invalid argument.

Comment: In the console write `groups` or `groups giorgio` to see your gid info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350141/in-unix-linux-how-to-you-find-out-what-group-a-given-user-is-in-via-command-line

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking again Jorge. when I type groups I get "staff com.apple.sharepoint.group.1 _lpadmin _appserveradm _appserverusr admin". What should I do now?

Comment: Maybe you are from group staff or admin. It doesnt matter that much, the important one is the www-data that is the apache, dont know if changes in Mac. To test you can just give 777 permissions to the folder and files (chmod -R 777 thefolder) without making chown

Answer (score 1):

You may also try like this to execute shell script in PHP:

```
<?php echo shell_exec('sh ./convertpngtif.sh');  ?>
```

or

```
<?php
$exec = file_get_contents("./convertpngtif.sh");
echo shell_exec($exec);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would diagnose the error by printing the error message first:

```
$out, $ret;
$exec = "/opt/local/bin/convert -adaptive-resize 150% ".$pos.".png ".$pos.".tif 2>&1";
exec($exec, $out, $ret);
var_dump($out);
```

It is VERY possible for imagemagick to cease running from exec() even though it runs properly from CLI because of permission problem, as other people have stated.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a **temporary target file**:

```
$source = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . $pos.".png";
$target = tempnam( '/tmp/', 'tif-' );
rename( $target, $target . '.tif' );
$target .= '.tif';

$command = '/opt/local/bin/convert';

assert( file_exists( $command ));
assert( file_exists( $source ));
assert( is_readable( $source ));
assert( ! file_exists( $target ));

$exec = $command . " -adaptive-resize 150% ". escapeshellarg( $source ) . " " . escapeshellarg( $target );
exec( $exec );
```